# Django ImportError: Module does not define attribute/class

Tags: python, django, importerror, django-shop

I am trying to add a custom/overridden AdminSite because I need a different template for the Admin. I did everything as the Docs said:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-the-default-admin-site

project/admin.py

```py
from django.contrib.admin import AdminSite 

class NewAdminSite(AdminSite):
    index_template = 'admin/index.html'
    site_header = 'Administration'

admin_site = NewAdminSite(name='newadmin')
```

project/apps.py

```py
class NewAdminConfig(AdminConfig):
    default_site = 'project.admin.NewAdminSite'
```

I don't have any other apps, project is my root directory
ofc I added admin_site.urls instead of admin.site.urls to urls.py, created a custom AdminConfig in apps.py, and added that new AdminConfig to installed Apps instead of django.contrib.admin.

The Problem is that I now receive this:

AdminSiteClass = import_string(apps.get_app_config('admin').default_site)

File "C:\Users\User.virtualenvs\ssccms-fGQRLLK4\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 24, in import_string
) from err

ImportError: Module "project.admin" does not define a "NewAdminSite" attribute/class

my folder structure:

manage.py

project

- admin
- settings
- urls
- apps
- static
- templates
- migrations

workdir

- sqlite
- media

node_modules

locale

pipfile.lock

pipfile

wsgi

hope this is enough for folder structure, it is the django-shop cookiecutter project example structure

EDIT:

yes, it was definitely a circular import error. My workaround now is simply using the given admin.site by writing:

```
admin.site.index_template = 'admin/newadminindextemplate.html'
```

it works! Which is actually all that I wanted. But the Documentation says the following
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#root-and-login-templates

> If you wish to change the index, login or logout templates, you are better off creating your own AdminSite instance.

I tried that:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#customizing-the-adminsite-class

instead of the overriding part I pasted in the first link in the question but now there is

> django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'cascade_texteditor_config' not found. 'cascade_texteditor_config' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

now my new question is:

is it necessary to create your own instance of the index template ? the Documentation says no explanation so are there any problems that I might run into at a later time by doing admin.site.index_template?

Comment: I corrected the django docs link. I dont understand the end of your comment - I just want to override the index_template attribute of django.contrib.admin.AdminSite, I dont have it written/defines anywhere else, I thought the code in admin.py was enough?

Comment: By that last part I was asking about the file name in which you wrote the class (you added this `project/admin.py`). Anyway everything looks ok... Can you add your directory structure to the question?

Comment: I hope this is what you meant with folder structure, but I think we have a misunderstanding here: i thought it would be enough to subclass AdminSite this way and just add / override the attributes/functions that I want to change / add in admin.py. I dont have it defined anywhere else, I am completely fine with AdminSite how it is now so I thought it would be sufficient to code it that way and that django could use any function defined in AdminSite if NewAdminSite inherits from it that way.

Comment: I am not saying that you need to do something more. I asked for the directory structure to understand where you get the error from. Looking at your directory structure everything looks fine though. All I can say is that perhaps there is some other `project.admin` that is being imported from somewhere or there might actually be something like `del NewAdminSite` in your `admin.py`.

Comment: okay I will investigate that, thank you so so much!

Comment: I agree with @AbdulAzizBarkat it seems like a missmatched import or something.

Answer (score 1):

I've just hit a similar error. It's a bit confusing, in my case it was due to a circular import.

In my case the following helped:

- convert imports from top of the file containing `NewAdminSite` class to local imports (inside of the function where they're needed
- move the instantiation of `admin_site` variable to a separate file

Neither of those problems is actually visible in the code you've pasted, but may give you an idea what to look for.